# Is my proof that an equivalence of categories induced and adjunction correct?

Tags: solution-verification, category-theory, adjoint-functors

$\newcommand{\A}{\mathscr{A}}\newcommand{\B}{\mathscr{B}}$This is a quick question - my proof is very short, but I’m suspicious of it.

> Suppose the categories $\A,\B$ are equivalent via the functors $F:\A\to\B,\,G:\B\to\A$ and natural isomorphisms $\varphi:FG\to1_{\B}\,\psi:1_{\A}\to GF$. We want to show that $F\dashv G$. To that end, it is simplest to consider terminal morphisms. Let $\varepsilon_B:=\varphi_B$ for every $B\in\B$. Then I claim $(G(B),\varepsilon_B)$ is always a terminal morphism from $F$ to $B$.
>
> Suppose $p:F(A)\to B$ in $\B$ for an arbitrary $A\in\A$. Consider the arrow $h:=\varphi_B^{-1}\circ p$: since $F$ is an equivalence of categories, it is full and faithful, therefore $h:F(A)\to FG(B)$ implies the existence of a *unique* $q:A\to G(B)$ such that $F(q)=h$. But then for all such $p$, there exists a unique $q$ such that $\varepsilon_B\circ F(q)=p$, so $(G(B),\varepsilon_B)$ is a terminal morphism from $F$ to $B$, so $F\dashv G$. $\blacksquare$

Why am I suspicious of this proof? Because I have been told from many sources that the isomorphisms that make $F,G$ equivalences are not the unit and counit of the adjunction, in general, but I have here used one of them as the counit. Have I done something wrong, or is this a correct proof?

Comment: Any equivalence can be made into an adjoint equivalence by modifying either the unit or the counit. Since in your proof you fix the counit, the unit of your adjunction may deviate from the original unit by an isomorphism.

Comment: @JonasLinssen Thanks for the clarification. It’s all ok then?

Comment: Yes, I’d say so…